# Python Multiprocessing with tqdm: Progress Bar Not Updating

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I'm using Python's multiprocessing module to speed up the computation of a feature from 3D LIDAR data. Each process computes the feature for a subset of the points in the data. I'm using tqdm to provide a progress bar for the computation, but the bar isn't updating as expected.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm import tqdm
from functools import partial

# np.random.seed(0)
lidar_data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=100.0, size=(1000, 3))

def compute_feature(i, lidar_data, radius):
    x_center, y_center, z_center = lidar_data[i]
    height = z_center
    bounding_box_x_min = x_center - radius - 5
    bounding_box_x_max = x_center + radius + 5
    bounding_box_y_min = y_center - radius - 5
    bounding_box_y_max = y_center + radius + 5
    points_in_cylinder = []
    z_height = []

    for point in lidar_data:
        x, y, z = point
        if bounding_box_x_min <= x <= bounding_box_x_max and bounding_box_y_min <= y <= bounding_box_y_max:
            if z <= z_center:
                dist_to_center = np.sqrt((x - x_center)**2 + (y - y_center)**2)
                if dist_to_center <= radius and z_center - height <= z:
                    points_in_cylinder.append(point)
                    z_height.append(z)

    points_in_cylinder = np.array(points_in_cylinder)
    z = [round(float(point[2]), 3) for point in points_in_cylinder]
    minimum_z = min(z) if points_in_cylinder.size > 0 else z_center
    feature = z_center - 2 * minimum_z
    return feature

# lidar_data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=100.0, size=(1000, 3))
radius = 3.0

with Pool() as pool:
    func = partial(compute_feature, lidar_data=lidar_data, radius=radius)
    features = list(tqdm(pool.imap(func, range(lidar_data.shape[0])), total= lidar_data.shape[0], desc="Computing feature"))

features = np.array(features)
```

When I run this code, the tqdm progress bar appears, but it doesn't update. It's as if the computation isn't starting at all. What could be the cause of this issue? How can I get the progress bar to update correctly?

Comment: Question: does the code eventually complete anyway, with the `features` list populated with the results, or does it just hang? And does the code work correctly when you don't use tqdm?

Comment: Please include the imports necessary for this please. Your code is not replicatable and cannot be run to help you

Comment: @someone The code is not completing. Maybe the way is use multiprocessing is wrong.

Comment: @AbilashReznovSubbaraman What do you mean by the imports necessary. All the libraries are in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried to reproduce your code, and the problem is not with tqdm, it's the way you're using `multiprocessing.Pool()`.

When I copied your code verbatim, I got an endless loop of errors telling me something about starting a new process when the first one was not fully initialized, and that's due to the fact that you launch the pool as you load the file instead of doing so in a `main()` function.

This code works:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm import tqdm
from functools import partial


def compute_feature(i, lidar_data, radius):
    x_center, y_center, z_center = lidar_data[i]
    height = z_center
    bounding_box_x_min = x_center - radius - 5
    bounding_box_x_max = x_center + radius + 5
    bounding_box_y_min = y_center - radius - 5
    bounding_box_y_max = y_center + radius + 5
    points_in_cylinder = []
    z_height = []

    for point in lidar_data:
        x, y, z = point
        if bounding_box_x_min <= x <= bounding_box_x_max and bounding_box_y_min <= y <= bounding_box_y_max:
            if z <= z_center:
                dist_to_center = np.sqrt((x - x_center)**2 + (y - y_center)**2)
                if dist_to_center <= radius and z_center - height <= z:
                    points_in_cylinder.append(point)
                    z_height.append(z)

    points_in_cylinder = np.array(points_in_cylinder)
    z = [round(float(point[2]), 3) for point in points_in_cylinder]
    minimum_z = min(z) if points_in_cylinder.size > 0 else z_center
    feature = z_center - 2 * minimum_z
    return feature

def main():
    # np.random.seed(0)
    lidar_data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=100.0, size=(1000, 3))
    # lidar_data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=100.0, size=(1000, 3))
    radius = 3.0

    with Pool() as pool:
        func = partial(compute_feature, lidar_data=lidar_data, radius=radius)
        features = list(tqdm(pool.imap(func, range(lidar_data.shape[0])), total= lidar_data.shape[0], desc="Computing feature"))

    features = np.array(features)
    print(features)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The only change I had to make was move all your "main" code into a function, and add a main guard to call it only once, from the primary process, and not from the forked processes that the pool creates.